# Setting up emacs on Cygwin

Tags: emacs, terminal, windows-vista, cygwin, mintty

I'm currently trying out Cygwin. I am trying to get emacs to open in terminal mode. When I run `$ emacs -nw` through mintty with the Cygwin shell. I get `bash: emacs: command not found`. I am running Windows Vista SP2 if that helps. I think you need to edit the environment variables but I don't know what to do then.

Please help! Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Updates:**

1. This is what comes up when I run `$ echo $PATH`:

   ```
   $ echo $PATH
   ```

   > `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Adobe/AGL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Roxio Shared/10.0/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/RoxioShared/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Roxio Shared/10.0/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Ulead Systems/MPEG:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/gtk2/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/mlt/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Console:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/OpenLibraries/bin`

Comment: i'm assuming you installed emacs?  (i don't believe it installed by default in cygwin).

Comment: what does "echo $PATH" output?  (emacs should be available from "/usr/bin/emacs").

Comment: @jtahlborn I added it in the question

Comment: which cygwin emacs packages did you install?

Comment: @jtahlborn none. Sorry about the echo $PATH thing its a bit messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `emacs -nw`, I'm pretty sure you're going to need to install the cygwin emacs (using the cygwin installer).

If you want to use some other emacs for Windows (I don't think `-nw` will work then), then you need to add the path to that emacs to your PATH, e.g.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/<path_to_emacs_dir>.
```

If you want that to be permanent, then you can add it to your ".bashrc" file.

Comment: So I just type "export PATH=${PATH}:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/"? It won't mess up anything right? I couldn't find any cygwin emacs in setup.exe. I tried just about everything. Or is it something else I need to download? Thanks for everything!

Comment: oops, my path didn't come out correctly, fixed that.  typing in a PATH won't mess up anything permanently.  if you mess it up, just restart mintty.  emacs _is_ available through setup.exe, and you must install that first if you want "emacs -nw" to work.

Comment: you have the latest setup.exe from cygwin.com?  what mirror are you using?

Comment: Aha! tweedo.com (the mirror that I was using) didn't have it. I checked a couple of other ones and found it!!! Thank you very much!